# set a goal in the inflated obstacles area

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my understanding, if we set a navigation goal in inflated obstacles, the navigation stack won't give a path plan. So, how can I configure the stack to let the it give a path plan, which navigate the robot to a position near the goal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9806/set-a-goal-in-the-inflated-obstacles-area/) by [Charles](https://answers.ros.org/users/333/charles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack will not plan a path to a goal given in an inflated obstacle because a cell marked as such guarantees that any concave robot footprint would be in collision if the center-point of that footprint were placed at that cell. Basically, if the navigation stack were to attempt to achieve such a goal, it would hit something.

If you want the navigation stack to get as close to this goal as possible, you might want to check out the "default_tolerance" parameter that can be set on navfn documented here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navfn#Parameters. Setting that parameter should allow you to specify goals inside of inflated obstacles where the robot will try to get close.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AravindaDP](https://answers.ros.org/users/27826/aravindadp/) on 2016-12-07**:
However seems this value is not used where it's supposed to use.

bool GlobalPlanner::makePlan(const PoseStamped& start, const PoseStamped& goal, double tolerance, std::vector& plan)

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/global_planner/src/planner_core.cpp#L222

**Comment by [AravindaDP](https://answers.ros.org/users/27826/aravindadp/) on 2016-12-07**:
Furthermore it is reported but not resolved yet.

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/262